# Add NSAttributedString to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm attempting to set an attributed string on my back bar button item.
This is my first attempt at attributed strings.
Here is the code:

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let barButtonBackStr = "< Back"
    var attributedBarButtonBackStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: barButtonBackStr as String)
    attributedBarButtonBackStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
        value: UIFont(
            name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold",
            size: 18.0)!,
        range: NSRange(
            location:0,
            length:1))
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: attributedBarButtonBackStr, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "barButtonBack:")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

This results in the following error in Xcode.

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIBarButtonItem' with an argument
>   list of type '(title: NSMutableAttributedString, style:
>   UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: CombatOutcomeViewController, action:
>   String)'

Anyone have an idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot directly set an attributed string to an `UIBarButtonItem`. You have to set a normal string to its title and then set the attributes for the title:

```
let barButtonBackStr = "< Back"
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : AnyObject] = [.font : UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", size: 18)!]
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: barButtonBackStr, style: .plain, target: self, action: "barButtonBack:")
newBackButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

This approach has one caveat: You cannot set a range for the attributes. It's all or nothing.

To define a range for the attributes you have to create a `UILabel`, set an attributed string to its `attributedText` property and then create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view:

```
let barButtonBackStr = "< Back"
let attributedBarButtonBackStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: barButtonBackStr as String)
attributedBarButtonBackStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,
    value: UIFont(
        name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold",
        size: 18.0)!,
    range: NSRange(
        location:0,
        length:1))
let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = attributedBarButtonBackStr
label.sizeToFit()
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

When you want to use this approach you have to know you have to set the target and the action to the custom view, because the `UIBarButtonItem` does not longer handle it. As it says in Apple's docs:

> The bar button item created by this method does not call the action
> method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the
> bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user
> interactions and provide an appropriate response.

Comment: Nice answer from a long time ago, making people's lives better for a long time...